mongoDB got hang/stuck forever sometimes when using single transaction for multiple write and update multiple collections
i have issue where i am using transactions for multiple update and create to multiple collections , the main function i use here something like this
    fn insert_one_transactional<P>(
        &self,
        mut params: InsertOneTransactionalParams<P>,
    ) -> Result<ResultInsertOneRepository, ErrorIdentifier>
    where
        P: DeserializeOwned + Unpin + Send + Sync + Serialize + Debug,
    {
        executor::block_on(async {
            let col = self.mongo.database.collection(params.col_name.to_owned().as_str());
            if params.transactional.is_none() {
                let session_result = self.mongo.client.start_session();

                let session = match session_result.await {
                    Ok(session) => session,
                    Err(err) => {
                        return Err(ErrorIdentifier {
                            hint: HINT_KEY_WRITE_DATA.to_string(),
                            details: None,
                            code: ErrorGlobal::Repository,
                            message: err.to_string(),
                        });
                    }
                };
                params.transactional = Some(session);
                match params.transactional.as_mut().unwrap().start_transaction().await {
                    Err(err) => {
                        // Handle the error here
                        return Err(self.process_error(err, params.col_name.to_owned()));
                    }
                    _ => {}
                }
            }
            let result = col.insert_one(params.doc).with_options(params.options).session(params.transactional.as_mut().unwrap()).await;

            match result {
                Ok(res) => {
                    Ok(ResultInsertOneRepository {
                        id: res.inserted_id.as_object_id().unwrap().to_hex(),
                        transactional: params.transactional.unwrap(),
                    })
                }
                Err(err) => {
                    return Err(self.process_error(err, params.col_name));
                }
            }
        })
    }

here is the pseducode for that function for a little explanations:
IF params transaction/session not exist
  THEN i create new transaction/session
  THEN start the transaction
  THEN assign that transaction/session to return to re use again
ELSE
  THEN call insert with transaction/session
  THEN assign that transaction/session to return to re use again
END

here is how i use the insert_one_transactional
   let params_insert_order_item = InsertOneTransactionalParams {
                col_name: EnumCollectionModel::OrderItem,
                options: None,
                doc: data_order_item.clone(),
                transactional: Option::from(trx),
            };

            let result_order_item = self.repository.insert_one_transactional(params_insert_order_item);
            if let Err(e) = result_order_item {
                return Err(lang.get_error_instance(e));
            }
            trx = result_order_item?.transactional;

sometimes the insert got hang and didnt give any response, so i cancel that request on POSTMAN and then re hit again and after re hit all operations Get and other writes got hang and didnt give any response on my all endpoint
but there is once or twice or sometimes i got this error:
Kind: Command failed: Error code 112 (WriteConflict): 
Caused by ::  :: Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction., 
labels: {\"TransientTransactionError\"}"

i got stuck now for few days to solved this
on my project i only using futures , not using Tokio
i am using latest rust version and latest mongodb version, i keep update my crates all the time :D
is that something wrong with the main function transaction ?
is that any setting to drop current session immediately ?
